# mutate error using dplyr package showing x Input `bhr6` can't be recycled to size 6

Tags: r, dplyr

thanks in advance for your help.

I'm trying to run a code that should group by variable, take a value between two dates. Then compute the cumulative product of the values.

Here's an example of the data frame which fully includes 10,344 observations:

```
Retlong <- Dataframe 
Name     date_effective     date6         date         value
736.AIG  2018-01-03         2018-07-03    2018-01-07   0.036
736.AIG  2018-01-03         2018-07-03    2018-01-13   -0.041
736.AIG  2018-01-03         2018-07-03    2019-01-01   0.481 

BHAR6 <- Retlong %>% 
  group_by(Name) %>% 
  filter(between (date, date_effective, date6)) %>%
  mutate(bhr6 = accumulate ((1 + value), '*')) %>% 
  as.data.frame() %>% 
  right_join(Retlong) %>% 
  arrange(desc(Name), date)
```

But I'm getting this error:
Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `bhr6`.
x Input `bhr6` can't be recycled to size 6.
i Input `bhr6` is `accumulate((1 + value), "*")`.
i Input `bhr6` must be size 6 or 1, not 3.
i The error occurred in group 1: Name = "9373.T^E17".

I am trying to make the dataframe look like this.

````
Name     date_effective     date6         date         value    bhr6
736.AIG  2018-01-03         2018-07-03    2018-01-07   0.036    (1+0.036)
736.AIG  2018-01-03         2018-07-03    2018-01-13   -0.041   (1+0.036)(1-0.041)
736.AIG  2018-01-03         2018-07-03    2019-01-01   0.481    N/A or 0 ```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you were looking for? I created an intermediate variable that tracks the `between()` logic so you can use it in the other calculation

EDIT: I think using two mutate calls with rowwise separate from group_by Name is probably what you wanted

```r
library(dplyr)

Retlong <-
  read.table(
    text = "Name     date_effective     date6         date          value
736.AIG  2018-01-03         2018-07-03    2018-01-07   0.036
736.AIG  2018-01-03         2018-07-03    2018-01-13   -0.041
736.AIG  2018-01-03         2018-07-03    2019-01-01   0.481"
  ,header = TRUE)

BHAR6 <- Retlong %>%
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(keeper = between(as.Date(date), as.Date(date_effective), as.Date(date6))) %>% 
  group_by(Name) %>% 
  mutate(bhr6 = cumprod(keeper*(1 + value))) %>% 
  right_join(Retlong) %>%
  arrange(desc(Name), date) %>% 
  as.data.frame()
#> Joining, by = c("Name", "date_effective", "date6", "date", "value")

BHAR6
#>      Name date_effective      date6       date  value keeper     bhr6
#> 1 736.AIG     2018-01-03 2018-07-03 2018-01-07  0.036   TRUE 1.036000
#> 2 736.AIG     2018-01-03 2018-07-03 2018-01-13 -0.041   TRUE 0.993524
#> 3 736.AIG     2018-01-03 2018-07-03 2019-01-01  0.481  FALSE 0.000000
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, and for trying. I figured out that the problem was with using '*' instead of `*`, which took me 2 days to figure out! :/ but now the code works.

Answer (score 0):

I realised that in my code I presented the * sign incorrectly, using '*' instead of `*`.

Solved now.